# How can I use Pyarrow connect to a remote HDFS?

Tags: python, hdfs, pyarrow

I need to use python to connect to a remote HDFS. One of the ways I found from google is to use pyarrow. Unfortunately, I got this error for this simple example. And I have no idea why this error occurs and how to solve it.

```
from pyarrow import fs
hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem('http://172.16.1.7', 8020)

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/notebooks/test/0.1-hdfs-test.py", line 2, in <module>
  hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem('http://172.16.1.7', 8020)
File "pyarrow/_hdfs.pyx", line 83, in pyarrow._hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.__init__
File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 122, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 99, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
OSError: Unable to load libjvm: /usr/java/latest//lib/server/libjvm.so: cannot open shared 
object file: No such file or directory
```

There are two machines in my environment that one of the machines is my working station where my code stay and the other one contains the HDFS that I would like to read/write data. I use anaconda as my python environment.
`Python=3.6.13`,`hdfs3=0.3.1`,`pyarrow=3.0.0`. Java installed on my Centos7 machine is jdk1.8.0_144.
I see someone solved their issue by setting HADOOP_HOME. However, I did not install Hadoop on my working machine, do I need to also install it?

Comment: Yes, you will need Hadoop installed on the working machine.  There are some special instructions for using pyarrow's hdfs interface.  Can you read [these instructions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#filesystem-hdfs) and let me know if they work for you.

Comment: Hello Pace, thanks for your comment. May I ask why would I need to also install Hadoop on my working machine?

Comment: It's a requirement of [libhdfs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html) which is used by pyarrow's `HadoopFileSystem`.  Digging around it does seem there was some older efforts to use [libhdfs3](https://github.com/erikmuttersbach/libhdfs3) which doesn't have this requirement but that project appears to be dead, possibly when [pivotal gave up building their own hadoop distribution](https://www.channele2e.com/software/big-data/pivotal-kills-hadoop-distribution-embraces-hortonworks/) but that is speculation.